# Wrong output using tree.xpath

Tags: python, lxml

Iam a beginner to data scraping.I want to extract all the marathon events name from a website [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_marathon_races)
For this I have written a small code :-

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_marathon_races')
tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
events = tree.xpath('//td/a[@class="new"]/text()')

print events
```

The problem is when I try to execute the following code,a blank array comes as an output.What is the problem with this code?It would be grateful if anyone can help me in correcting or finding mistakes my code.

Comment: Could you please provide the input ou are using?

Comment: I get a [SiteLock](https://www.sitelock.com/) page when I load that site. You don't get the original page until you answer a captcha. You should always take a look at what `requests` fetched, servers are not required to send the same thing to every HTTP client.

Comment: the website mentioned in the variable page is the input

Comment: @MartijnPieters:I didn't encounter this problem, while trying to open the posted link. :\

Comment: @user3186829 try running your own code and open the site afterwards, you will get this warning. Or try inspecting the result of requests.get in your code.

Comment: @user3186829: open the browser in an incognito / private browsing window. You have probably already filled in the captcha before, or there are other heuristics that server applies before letting your see it that you meet with using your browser.

Comment: @MartijnPieters:You are right.Some sitelock webpage opens in normal window after executing the program.What should I do to avoid it?

Comment: @user3186829: I don't know; SiteLock uses proprietary techniques to prevent exactly what you are trying to do, scrape the site. I'm sure that they are doing their best to not make it easy to circumvent.

Comment: @MartijnPieters:Now I have changed the website in the code,can you check what's wrong with it?

Comment: @user3186829: and you get data in `events`. So what is the problem there?

Comment: @MartijnPieters:Event is printing blank array

Comment: @user3186829: no, it doesn't for me, not for the Wikipedia page.

Comment: Yeah it is resolved.Thanks Martjin:)